# Чем заменить функции из php при реализации кода на Java?

Tags: php, java

Хочу реализовать [этот php код](https://github.com/rembish/TextAtAnyCost/blob/master/rtf.php) на java, однако php не знаю. Встретил пару незнакомых мне операторов и функций. Помогите, разобраться, пожалуйста.

Правильно ли я перенес реализацию этих функций?

php-код:

```
function rtf_isPlainText($s) {
$failAt = array("*", "fonttbl", "colortbl", "datastore", "themedata", "stylesheet", "info", "picw", "pich");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($failAt); $i++)
    if (!empty($s[$failAt[$i]])) return false;
return true;
}
```

Java код:

```
 private boolean rtfIsPlainText (String textOnFile){
    String [] notASimpleText = {"*", "colortbl", "datastore", "themedata", "stylesheet", "info", "picw", "pich"};

    for (int i =0; i< notASimpleText.length; i++)if (textOnFile == notASimpleText[i]) return false;
    return true;
};
```

php код:

```
 function from_macRoman($c) {
$table = array(
    0x83 => 0x00c9, 0x84 => 0x00d1, 0x87 => 0x00e1, 0x8e => 0x00e9, 0x92 => 0x00ed, 
    0x96 => 0x00f1, 0x97 => 0x00f3, 0x9c => 0x00fa, 0xe7 => 0x00c1, 0xea => 0x00cd, 
    0xee => 0x00d3, 0xf2 => 0x00da
);
if (isset($table[$c]))
    $c = "&#x".sprintf("%04x", $table[$c]).";";
return $c;
}
```

java-код:

```
public String getCodes(String ch) {

    String result ="";
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> associativeArray = new HashMap<>(13);
    associativeArray.put(0x83, 0x00c9);
    associativeArray.put(0x00d1, 0x87);
    associativeArray.put(0x87, 0x00e1);
    associativeArray.put(0x8e, 0x00e9);
    associativeArray.put(0x92, 0x00ed);
    associativeArray.put(0x96, 0x00f1);
    associativeArray.put(0x97, 0x00f3);
    associativeArray.put(0x9c, 0x00fa);
    associativeArray.put(0xe7, 0x00c1);
    associativeArray.put(0xea, 0x00cd);
    associativeArray.put(0xee, 0x00d3);
    associativeArray.put(0xf2, 0x00da);

    for (int i = 0; i < associativeArray.size(); i++) {
        if (associativeArray.get(i)== Integer.parseInt(ch, 16)){
           result = ch.replaceAll("&#x", "%04x");
           break;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Чем можно заменить оператор `.=` и функцию `html_entity_decode` из `php` при реализации на java?

Comment: `.=` что то типа `string = string + "string"` не думаю что все тут php программисты отлично знают синтаксис java

Comment: @Naumov Ну мне достаточного одного php программиста, который знает синтаксис java, но если их больше, я не обижусь) И если их нет, то тоже не обижусь))

Comment: Ясно `html_entity_decode` декодирует сущности html в символы типа `<` = `&lt;` и так далее. `.=` - означает добавить к текущей строке следующую, если в жава есть оператор для строк `+=` то это он и есть

Comment: @Naumov в java есть += но и в php он тоже вроде бы есть (с числами точно), почему бы его не использовать?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH потому что в PHP он не работает со строками и используется специальный знак конкатенации `.`

Comment: @AlexKrass понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH в добавок `$s[$failAt[$i]]` - отсюда получается, что `$s` это `array`, а не `String textOnFile`. И на большинство `isset( )` или `empty( )` можно вызвать Java функции на подобии `HashMap -> containsKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. По первому коду.

Если его слегка переписать, то он примет такой вид

```php
function rtf_isPlainText($s) {
  $failAt = array(.......);
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($failAt); $i++) {
    $val = $failAt[$i];
    if (!empty($s[$val]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Т.е. мы пробегаем по всем значениям из `$failAt` и проверяем не пустое ли значение из **массива** `s` для этого ключа. Т.е. на Java это будет как-то так

```java
boolean rtf_isPlainText(Map<String, String> s) {
  String[] failAt = {.......};
  for (int i = 0; i < failAt.length; i++) {
    String val = failAt[i];
    String test = s.get(val)
    if (test != null && !test.isEmpty())
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

Во втором коде происходит конвертация **символа** в entity. Соответственно java код будет такой

```java
   public String getCodes(char ch) {
        // Лучше вынести в статические константы
        HashMap<Character, Integer> associativeArray = new HashMap<>(13);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x83, 0x00c9);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x00d1, 0x87);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x87, 0x00e1);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x8e, 0x00e9);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x92, 0x00ed);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x96, 0x00f1);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x97, 0x00f3);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0x9c, 0x00fa);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0xe7, 0x00c1);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0xea, 0x00cd);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0xee, 0x00d3);
        associativeArray.put((char) 0xf2, 0x00da);

        Integer val = associativeArray.get(ch);
        if (val != null) {
            return String.format("%04x", val);
        }
        return String.valueOf(ch);
    }
```